# Defining custom constructor for a SystemC module

Tags: c++, systemc

I have a SystemC module as below and I want to pass on "maps" to the constructor. How can I do it?

```
struct Detector: sc_module
{
    map <int,int> int_map;

    SC_CTOR(Detector)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i<10; i++)
        {
          int_map[i]= map[i][0];
        }
    }
};
```

For example, I want to instantiate this module 4 times with 4 different maps.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to add a parameter to the constructor? This seems the easiest solution, but it's too easy - does anything prevent you from doing this?

Comment: I would use a normal constructor and not the 'SC_CTOR'.  And, as anatolyg said, pass the parameter to that constructor.  I think you still have to add 'SC_HAS_PROCESS(Detector) to the code.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes using a normal constructor worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [SystemC Language Reference Manual](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1666/download/1666-2011.pdf):

> The use of macro `SC_CTOR` is not obligatory. Using `SC_CTOR`, it is not possible to add user-defined arguments to the constructor. If an application needs to pass additional arguments, the constructor shall be provided explicitly. This is a useful coding idiom.

Because of that, I think you're better off not using `SC_CTOR` at all. Our company's SystemC coding style recommends just that.

There is one proviso though: if you use the process macros (`SC_METHOD` or `SC_THREAD`) then you must also use `SC_HAS_PROCESS`.

Here's a complete example of something like what you are after:

```cpp
#include <systemc>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace sc_core;

struct Detector : public sc_module {

    typedef map<int, vector<int> > input_map_t;

    Detector(sc_module_name name, input_map_t& input_map)
        : sc_module(name)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < input_map.size(); i++) {
            int_map[i] = input_map[i][0];
        }
        SC_METHOD(process);
    }

    void process() {}

    map<int, int> int_map;
    SC_HAS_PROCESS(Detector);
};

int sc_main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Detector::input_map_t input_map;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        input_map[i] = vector<int>();
        input_map[i].push_back(i);
    }

    Detector d("d", input_map);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you comment out the `SC_HAS_PROCESS` line, you'll see a string of compilation errors.

Comment: Thank you Darry ! It works. How can I do the same with a 2d array. Because I have 4 arrays of different dimensions,but the second dimension is fixed as 2. I am trying to take 4 different 2d arrays( of type uint64 )through the constructor and use it in a function during runtime.But I get an error saying that dimensions should be fixed and could not access the values from the arrays.

Comment: And I am using C++ 98.

Comment: I am not clear on what you are asking here. What data type are you using for the 2d arrays? I recommend using std::vector. If you like, perhaps post a separate question with an example code snippet. It sounds like a pure C++ question.